# Producing all combinations of two column values in R

Tags: r, combinations

I have a data.frame with two columns

```
> data.frame(a=c(5,4,3), b =c(1,2,4))
  a b
1 5 1
2 4 2
3 3 4
```

I want to produce a list of data.frames with different combinations of those column values; there should be a total of six possible scenarios for the above example (correct me if I am wrong):

```
  a b
1 5 1
2 4 2
3 3 4

  a b
1 5 1
2 4 4
3 3 2

  a b
1 5 2
2 4 1
3 3 4

  a b
1 5 2
2 4 4
3 3 1

  a b
1 5 4
2 4 2
3 3 1

  a b
1 5 4
2 4 1
3 3 2
```

Is there a simple function to do it? I don't think **expand.grid** worked out for me.

Comment: you only care about the second column? `apply(gtools::permutations(3, 3, dd$b), 1, function(x) within(dd, b <- x))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually `expand.grid` **can work** here, but it is **not recommended** since it's rather inefficient when you have many rows in `df` (you need to subset `n!` out of `n**n` if you have `n` rows).

Below is an example using `expand.grid`

```
u <- do.call(expand.grid, rep(list(seq(nrow(df))), nrow(df)))
lapply(
  asplit(
    subset(
      u,
      apply(u, 1, FUN = function(x) length(unique(x))) == nrow(df)
    ), 1
  ), function(v) within(df, b <- b[v])
)
```

---

One more efficient option is to use `perms` from package `pracma`

```
library(pracma)
> lapply(asplit(perms(df$b),1),function(v) within(df,b<-v))
[[1]]
  a b
1 5 4
2 4 2
3 3 1

[[2]]
  a b
1 5 4
2 4 1
3 3 2

[[3]]
  a b
1 5 2
2 4 4
3 3 1

[[4]]
  a b
1 5 2
2 4 1
3 3 4

[[5]]
  a b
1 5 1
2 4 2
3 3 4

[[6]]
  a b
1 5 1
2 4 4
3 3 2
```

Comment: can you correct? *could not find function "asplit"*

Comment: @ToNoY `asplit` is from base R. Which version of R are you using? Mine is 4.0.3

Answer (score 1):

Using `combinat::permn` create all possible permutations of `b` value and for each bind it with `a` column.

```
df <- data.frame(a= c(5,4,3), b = c(1,2,4))
result <- lapply(combinat::permn(df$b), function(x) data.frame(a = df$a, b = x))
result

#[[1]]
#  a b
#1 5 1
#2 4 2
#3 3 4

#[[2]]
#  a b
#1 5 1
#2 4 4
#3 3 2

#[[3]]
#  a b
#1 5 4
#2 4 1
#3 3 2

#[[4]]
#  a b
#1 5 4
#2 4 2
#3 3 1

#[[5]]
#  a b
#1 5 2
#2 4 4
#3 3 1

#[[6]]
#  a b
#1 5 2
#2 4 1
#3 3 4
```